# Need simple replaceInCell apps script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to create a function that does something extremely simple in Google Sheets. Unfortunately, I'm new to Apps Scripts. I intend to connect the function to a custom menu (which I've learned how to create).

Basically, the script needs to do this:

In a single cell (say perhaps, G2, because it really will be G2): If the content of G2 is 0 then change it to 1; on next use, if the content of G2 is 1 then change it back to 0; and so on. **In other words, I'm looking for something that will simply toggle the contents of a single cell between two values.**

I apologize in advance for requesting this kind of hand-holding, but I'm presuming this is the simplest thing, and it's also likely the first and last Apps Script I'll need to use this decade. Anyone's help would be roundly appreciated.

Randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be this:

```
  function setOneCell() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var range = sheet.getRange('A1');
    var data = range.getValue();
    if(data === 0) range.setValue(1);
    if(data === 1) range.setValue(0);
  }
```

Comment: Jason, appreciated, that did it. Thanks so much for taking the time.